# Random "unhandled exception" when called glBufferData()

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation

I have some OpenGL code that runs perfectly, but every now and then (about every fifth time or so) when I try to launch the program, it crashes with unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5CE5F86E (atioglxx.dll) in Main.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0x07388000.
```

The line it points to is just a simple glBufferData() call:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &m_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Is there something I can do about it? Or is it a graphics driver problem? I do have the latest drivers installed (the card is Radeon 290X). The crash is really inconsistent; without any changes, if I just keep launching the program, it usually takes a couple of times before it does this.

Comment: `The crash is really inconsistent` Sounds like undefined behavior, you're probably going to have to at least provide the code where you initialize `m_indices`.

Comment: @user657267 the `m_indices` is just a simple ~list~ vector of unsigned short {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0}.

Comment: And by simple list you mean `std::list`? You do realise that the storage of lists is not contiguous? Use a vector.

Comment: Err yeah, it's a vector. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then again I should have known due to the `[]`, sorry.

Comment: Are you sure that `sizeof(unsigned short) == sizeof(GLuint)`?

Comment: Good catch, I'll change that and test if it still keeps crashing.

Comment: @user657267 Whaddyaknow, it seems to work now - launched it about thirty times and no crashes. Please make your comment an answer. :)

Comment: For future reference you should always use the `sizeof` one of the elements to avoid problems like this, it will also avoid bugs if you happen to change the value type later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments it seems that you have a type size mismatch, change your call to

```
lBufferData(
  GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
  m_indices.size() * sizeof m_indices[0], 
  m_indices.data(),
  GL_STATIC_DRAW
);
```

You could also use a small helper function like the following to cut down on the crud (which helps avoid bugs like this)

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
size_t sizeof_vec(std::vector<T, Allocator> const& v)
{
  return v.size() * sizeof(T);
}

lBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof_vec(m_indices), m_indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```